# Access webserver of VM

Tags: networking, apache2, vmware-player

I have a problem with accessing my apache webserver (who is running on my VM) from my Windows 7 host. I check the ip address with `ifconfig`and then try to browse that IP address on my Windows 7 it says: webpage not available. But on my VM it works (with localhost).

I tried to put the VM on Host-Only but then it does not get any ip adress.

Maybe after fixing that it works? anyone knows how to fix?

Comment: what is your network type in VM is it NAT or bridged or what?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: It is running on NAT now but I also tried Host-Only, but then I don't get a ip adress

Comment: Try bridged and give an IP for your VM and then try

Comment: Ok I'm going to post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your choosing the network type.

So what you have to do is choosing `bridged` as network type for your VM.

then give it an IP in same range of your host.

And that's